# How to create a console command in Symfony2 application

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6, symfony-components, symfony-console

I need to create a console command for a Symfony2 application and I read docs [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) and [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html) though I am not sure what of those I should follow. So this is what I did.

- Create a file under `/src/PDI/PDOneBundle/Console/PDOneSyncCommand.php`
- Write this code:

  ```
  namespace PDI\PDOneBundle\Console\Command;

  use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

  class PDOneSyncCommand extends Command
  {
      protected function configure()
      {
          $this
              ->setName('pdone:veeva:sync')
              ->setDescription('Some description');
      }

      protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
      {
          $name = $input->getArgument('name');
          if ($name) {
              $text = 'Hello '.$name;
          } else {
              $text = 'Hello';
          }

          if ($input->getOption('yell')) {
              $text = strtoupper($text);
          }

          $output->writeln($text);
      }
  }
  ```

  - Create a file under `/bin`
  - Write this code:

    ## ! /usr/bin/env php

    require __ DIR __ .'/vendor/autoload.php';

    use PDI\PDOneBundle\Console\Command\PDOneSyncCommand;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

    $application = new Application();
    $application->add(new PDOneSyncCommand());
    $application->run();

But when I go to console by running `php app/console --shell` and hit `ENTER` I can't see the command registered, what I am missing?

NOTE: Can someone with more experience than me format the second piece of code properly?

**UPDATE 1**

Ok, following suggestions and taking answer as a start point I built this piece of code:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $container = $this->getContainer();

    $auth_url = $container->get('login_uri')."/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=".$container->get('client_id')."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($container->get('redirect_uri'));

    $token_url = $container->get('login_uri')."/services/oauth2/token";
    $revoke_url = $container->get('login_uri')."/services/oauth2/revoke";

    $code = $_GET['code'];

    if (!isset($code) || $code == "") {
        die("Error - code parameter missing from request!");
    }

    $params = "code=".$code
        ."&grant_type=".$container->get('grant_type')
        ."&client_id=".$container->get('client_id')
        ."&client_secret=".$container->get('client_secret')
        ."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($container->get('redirect_uri'));

    $curl = curl_init($token_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($status != 200) {
        die("Error: call to token URL $token_url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error ".curl_error(
                $curl
            ).", curl_errno ".curl_errno($curl));
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

    $access_token = $response['access_token'];
    $instance_url = $response['instance_url'];

    if (!isset($access_token) || $access_token == "") {
        die("Error - access token missing from response!");
    }

    if (!isset($instance_url) || $instance_url == "") {
        die("Error - instance URL missing from response!");
    }

    $output->writeln('Access Token ' . $access_token);
    $output->writeln('Instance Url ' . $instance_url);
}
```

But any time I invoke the task I got this error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>   You have requested a non-existent service "login_uri".

Why? Can't I access paramters on `parameter.yml` file? Where I am failing?

Comment: Following your edit, I'd rather use the `ContainerAwareCommand` child class to only **run** a service. Not sure having all this code inside the `execute()` command is good practice. Has my answer helped you?

Comment: @D4V1D yes, both answers help me, I am moving the code to yours and will test soon, will let you know if I have any problem. If I register the controller as a service can I still using it as a normal controller? I want to use it the same from a backend from web also later

Comment: It's tricky but possible. Let me know and I'll help you achieve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading article about `Console Component`. This is slightly different than registering a command in your bundle.

First, your class should live in Namespace `Command`, and it must include the Command prefix in classname. You've mostly done that. I will show you a sample command to grasp the idea so you can continue working with that as a base.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

// I am extending ContainerAwareCommand so that you can have access to $container
// which you can see how it's used in method execute
class HelloCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {

    // This method is used to register your command name, also the arguments it requires (if needed)
    protected function configure() {
        // We register an optional argument here. So more below:
        $this->setName('hello:world')
            ->addArgument('name', InputArgument::OPTIONAL);
    }

    // This method is called once your command is being called fron console.
    // $input - you can access your arguments passed from terminal (if any are given/required)
    // $output - use that to show some response in terminal
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        // if you want to access your container, this is how its done
        $container = $this->getContainer();

        $greetLine = $input->getArgument('name') 
            ? sprintf('Hey there %s', $input->getArgument('name')) 
            : 'Hello world called without arguments passed!'
        ;

        $output->writeln($greetLine);
    }

}
```

Now, running `app/console hello:world'` you should see a simple `Hello world` at your terminal.

Hope you got the idea, dont hesitate to ask if you have questions.

*Edit*

In Commands you cant directly access request, because of scopes. But you can pass arguments when you call your command. In my example I've registered optional argument which leads to two different outputs.

If you call your command like this `app/console hello:world` you get this output

> Hello world called without arguments passed!

but if you provide a name like this `app/console hello:world Demo` you get the following result:

> Hey there Demo

Comment: That works perfectly and I just have one remaining doubt, how do I access request on here? I am creating a command to perform tasks like the ones shown [here](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php) and that includes cURL calls and response from Salesforce, how I should handle this? Can you improve your question with a quick example?

Comment: You should make all your actions within a controller and register this controller as a service. You'd be able to inject whatever is needed in the controller and call it (in this `HelloCommand` class) by doing `$this->get('my_service');`.

Comment: @D4V1D my intention is to build a command because I need to run it as a CronJob task, will your suggestion work in this case? Can you write an example? (a little one just for take the whole idea?)

Comment: @ReynierPM I'll write an answer, don't hesitate to upvote it if it helped you (as you have already accepted this answer).

Comment: @ReynierPM I've added a bit more info about arguments and the use of them.

Comment: @Artamiel I think you misunderstood my point, I am not talking about passing parameters through command line when command is invoked, I am taking about access `request` parameters but anyway I've tried your solution and can't access to `parameters.yml` values, can you take a look to my edit?

Comment: `->get()` refers to service ID. Try with `->getParameter()`.

Answer (score 1):

Following Artamiel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30892686/2788131) and the comments below, here what you would need to build a command run as a CRON task (at least, this is how I've done it):

- First, declare your `SalesforceCommand` class:

  ```
  <?php
  class SalesforceCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
  {
      protected function configure()
      {
          $this
              ->setName('pdone:veeva:sync')
              ->setDescription('Doing some tasks, whatever...');
      }

      protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
      {    
          $myService = $this->getContainer()->get('my.service');

          $returnValue = $myService->whateverAction();

          if($returnValue === true)
              $output->writeln('Return value of my.service is true');
          else
              $output->writeln('An error occured!');
      }
  }
  ```
- Then, create your controller in whatever bundle you want:

  ```
      <?php
      namespace My\MyBundle\Service;          

      use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

      class ServiceController extends Controller
      {
          private $_rs;

          public function __construct(RequestStack $rs)
          {
              $this->_rs = $rs;
          }

          public function whateverAction()
          {
              $request = $this->_rs->getCurrentRequest();

              // do whatever is needed with $request.

              return $expectedReturn ? true : false;
          }
      }
  ```
- Finally, register your Controller as a Service in `app/config/services.yml`

  ```
  services:
      my.service:
          class: My\MyBundle\Service\ServiceController
          arguments: ["@request_stack"]
  ```

<sup>[(*as of Symfony 2.4, instead of injecting the request service, you should inject the request_stack service and access the Request by calling the getCurrentRequest() method*)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#injecting-the-request)</sup>

- You are finally able to use run it in as a CRON job by adding the following to your crontab (for it to run every minute):

  ```
  * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/your/project/app/console pdone:veeva:sync 1>>/path/to/your/log/std.log 2>>/path/to/your/log/err.log
  ```

Hope that helps!